# awk script that extracts prime numbers from a file

Tags: ubuntu, awk, gsub

I'm trying to write an AWK script that would check if there are any prime numbers in a file and print them. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

function is_prime(n) {
    if (n <= 1) return 0;
    if (n == 2) return 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

{
    gsub(/[^[:digit:]]/, " ");
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (is_prime($i)) {
            print $i;
        }
    }
}
```

i executed with a file containing the following text:

```
Math is179day foun193dary 
18
nachum17
19
```

It should print:

```
179
193
17
19
```

but it rather prints:

```
14
5
5
```

What is wrong with my code please?

edit: I would like to add that if replace the 'print i' line with 'print $i' then execute the script, no numbers are printed but only 3 blank lines.

Comment: I don't believe you: I don't get that output from your posted code -- only if I change the `print $i` to `print i` instead. Check what you are running. For `print i` the problem is that the loop inside your `is_prime` function uses, and changes, the same variable `i` being used in the outer loop that _calls_ `is_prime`.

Comment: @markp-fuso if I am not mistaken it simple check if there is any number bigger or equal 2 and less or equal square root which does divide number evenly, so it is basically brute-force approach, but making using of observation that it is enough to check up to square root due to commutativity of multiplication

Answer (score 3):

Your `is_prime` function code is alright, however problem is use of variable `i` inside the function and outside without letting function know that `i` is local. You can bypass this problem by declaring an additional argument in function signature and preserve original value of `i` outside.

[Read: How to make a variable local to a function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variable-Scope.html)

You may use this `awk` script:

```bash
function is_prime(n,   sq, i) {
    if (n <= 1) return 0
    if (n == 2) return 1
    sq = sqrt(n)
    for (i = 2; i <= sq; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) return 0
    }
    return 1
}
{
    gsub(/[^[:digit:]]+/, " ")
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if (is_prime($i)) {
            print $i
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after i changed the print i to print $i, i tried running the script on ubuntu and instead of printing numbers, it printed 3 empty lines. am i missing something on my computer maybe or an extra command?

Comment: Do you have function signature as `function is_prime(n,  i)` (shown in my answer)

Comment: just noticed it now and completely fixed my code. thank you so much!!

Comment: @anubhava : why are you calling `sqrt(n)` every single round of the `for(..)` loop ?

Comment: Good point. I didn't change OP's original `is_prime` code, just fixed local variable issue. Anyway, it is fixed now.